# Protobuf-net and Unity3D types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I have question about [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) in Unity3d.
Is it possible to serialize unity3d types: GameObject.
Example, I have in class property with type GameObject, this class serializedd/deserialized?

```
using ProtoBuf;
using UnityEngine;
...

[ProtoContract]  
public class Example 
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public int Count {get;set;}
   [ProtoMember(2)]
   public string Name {get;set;}
   [ProtoMember(3)]
   public GameObject MyGameObject {get;set;}  // ???
}
```

Sorry, my english..

Comment: Could you provide the syntax for assigningGameObjectas RunTimeTypeModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell protobuf-net which classes and properties you want to serialize. As you can't decorate `GameObject` with attributes, there is different means to do that.

You can do this for example with `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`, here an example for class `Point`, it sets properties `X` and `Y` to be serialized.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default
       .Add(typeof(System.Windows.Point), false).Add("X", "Y");
```

Your `GameObject` will have to have a default constructor in this case.

Comment: Could you provide the syntax for assigning`GameObject`as RunTimeTypeModel