# Protobuf-Net NotSupportedException: Type cannot be represented as a default value for closed immutable type (UnityEngine.Vector3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Following the answers to [How to serialize a closed immutable type with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18405160/4586051) and [Protobuf-net and Unity3D types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25987108/4586051), I've tried implementing a serializer that can handle UnityEngine's Vector3 container, the only important values of which are Vector3.x, Vector3.y and Vector3.z:

Using the following TypeModel:

```
serializer = TypeModel.Create();
serializer.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false;
```

Then I tried two different methods, separately, of adding a protocol definition for Vector3; an explicit definition:

```
serializer.Add(typeof(Vector3), false).Add(1, "x").Add(2, "y").Add(3, "z");
```

And using a surrogate:

```
serializer.Add(typeof(Vector3), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(SurrogateVector3));
```

With surrogate class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public sealed class SurrogateVector3
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    float x; 
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    float y; 
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    float z;

    public SurrogateVector3()
    {}

    public SurrogateVector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector3(SurrogateVector3 v)
    {
        return new Vector3(v.x, v.y, v.z);
    }

    public static implicit operator SurrogateVector3(Vector3 v)
    {
        return new SurrogateVector3(v.x, v.y, v.z);
    }
}
```

When using either method to try and serialize a `Dictionary<int, Vector3>`, the following exception is thrown:

```
NotSupportedException: Type cannot be represented as a default value: UnityEngine.Vector3
ProtoBuf.Serializers.DefaultValueDecorator.EmitBranchIfDefaultValue (ProtoBuf.Compiler.CompilerContext ctx, ProtoBuf.Compiler.CodeLabel label) (at <5e93d5bf6f2048709aab19aea88deb74>:0)
...
```

I'm unsure of how to modify my Typemodel or protocol definitions in order to successfully serialize collections of UnityEngine.Vector3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably a bug in the "map" code, which needs fixing. You can probably avoid it for now by adding:

```
[ProtoMap(DisableMap = true)]
```

to the property/field that is the dictionary. The difference between the "map" code and the original pre-"map" code is subtle and not very interesting - it mostly changes what happens in the case of duplicates - but: it would seem that there's an annoying bug in the "map" logic, that *probably* doesn't exist in the original code path. However, the "map" path is now the default, hence the workaround of disabling it.

Comment: I encoutered the same bug with a property defined like this: public Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, bool>> Workflows { get; set; }